# Given an orthogonal basis on Rm, is it possible to find an expression for vectors 1 and 0 in terms of this basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I was wondering if the following statement is correct:

Let {$u_1, u_2, ..., u_m$} be an orthogonal basis of $R^m$ with $u_r=(u_{r,1},...,u_{r,m})$ for $1\leq r\leq m$. Then:

$\textbf{1)}  \frac{u_{1,k} ^ 2}{ | u_1 | ^ 2} + \cdots + \frac{u_{m, k} ^ 2}{ | u_m | ^ 2} = 1$ for all $1\leq k\leq m$.

$\textbf{2)} \frac{u_{1,k}u_{1,s}}{|u_1|^2}+\cdots +\frac{u_{m,k}u_{m,s}}{|u_m|^2} =0$ for all $1\leq s,k\leq m$ with $k\neq s$.

for $m = 2$ this is a simple case, but for $m> 2$ I can't think of a proof or a counterexample ... can someone please help me?

$\textbf{NOTE:}$ I'm considering the usal norm |.| in $R^m$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the matrix with entries $a_{i,j}=\frac{u_{i,j}}{|u_i|}$. We are given that the rows of $A$ are orthogonal, i.e., $AA^T$ is a diagonal matrix. In fact, the diagonal entries turn out to be $\frac{u_i\cdot u_i}{|u_i|^2}=1$, so we have $AA^T=I$. Then also  $A^TA=I$, whch turns out to be your claim.

Comment: you are very right!...thank you